# Did Chaitanya ever meet Parashurama?

Tags: parashurama, chaitanya, chaitanya-charitamrita

Any biography of Chaitanya Mahaprabhu says about Chaitanya Mahaprabhu meeting Parashurama?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, [here](http://www.vedabase.com/en/cc/madhya/9/198) is what the Chaitanya Charitamrita says:

> At Durvaśana Śrī Caitanya Mahāprabhu visited the temple of Lord Rāmacandra, and on the hill known as Mahendra-śaila He saw Lord Paraśurāma.

Here is what Srila Prabhupada says about this verse:

> In Durvaśana, or Darbhaśayana (now known as Tiruppullani), which is seven miles east of Ramnad, there is a temple of Lord Rāmacandra. The hill known as Mahendra-śaila is near Tirunelveli, and at the end of this hill is a city known as Tiruchendur. West of Mahendra-śaila is the territory of Tribāṅkura. There is mention of Mahendra-śaila in the Rāmāyaṇa.

Comment: Do you know where I can download the pdf of Chaitanya Charitamrita in English? I do not want to read it online, unless there is no such pdf available.